# Sum of the reciprocals of whole numbers adding to one

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, mathematics

I have written some code which works out which sums of reciprocals of whole numbers sum to one, e.g:

\$\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\frac 16  =1 \$

\$\frac 17 +\frac 18 +\frac 19 + \frac1{10} + \frac1{11}+ \frac1{14}+ \frac1{15}+ \frac1{18} + \frac1{20}+ \frac1{22}+ \frac1{24} + \frac1{28}+ \frac1{30} + \frac1{33}=1 \$

RecipSumToOneCalc class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Works out which reciprocals sum to one e.g. 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/6 = 1
/// </summary>
public class RecipSumToOneCalc
{
    private readonly byte max;
    private readonly bool allowRepetitions;
    private Dictionary<Fraction, CachedResult> cache;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new RecipSumToOneCalc
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="max">The maximum denominator, inclusive</param>
    /// <param name="allowRepetitions">if true repetitions are allowed e.g. 1/2 + 1/2 = 1; if false they are not</param>
    public RecipSumToOneCalc(byte max, bool allowRepetitions=true)
    {
        this.max = max;
        this.allowRepetitions = allowRepetitions;
        cache = new Dictionary<Fraction, CachedResult>();   
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to store the results of Decompose in the cache
    /// </summary>
    private class CachedResult
    {
        public byte Min;
        public List<byte[]> Results;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the result of the calculation
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Each array is a series of reciprocals which sums to the number 1; the elements of the array are the denominators of the reciprocals</returns>
    public List<byte[]> Decompose()
    {
        return Decompose(1, Fraction.One) ?? new List<byte[]>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Divides a number by another, returning the result rounded up 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">the dividend</param>
    /// <param name="b">the divisor</param>
    /// <returns>the quotient, if necessary rounded up to the nearest whole number</returns>
    private static long DivideRoundUp(long a, long b)
    {
        return (a - 1) / b + 1;
    }

    private List<byte[]> Decompose(byte min, Fraction f)
    {         
        if (min>max)    //there are no numbers in the range (min to max) so there can be no results!
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte theMin = Math.Max((byte)DivideRoundUp(f.Denominator, f.Numerator), min);
        if(theMin<=max)
        {
            CachedResult cachedResult;
            List<byte[]> result;
            if (cache.TryGetValue(f, out cachedResult))
            {
                if (cachedResult.Min == min)    //found exact match from the cache, just use this
                {
                    return cachedResult.Results;
                }
                if (cachedResult.Min <= min)    //match on the fraction found but the minimum is lower so need to remove invalid results
                {
                    result = cachedResult.Results.Where(a => a[0] >= min).ToList();
                    return result;
                }
            }

            result = new List<byte[]>();
            for (byte n = theMin; n <= max; n++)
            {
                Fraction oneOver = new Fraction(1, n);
                Fraction remainder = f.Subtract(oneOver);
                if (remainder.IsZero())
                {
                    result.Add(new byte[] { n });   //there is no remainder so an array with a single element is returned
                }
                else
                {
                    List<byte[]> subResults = Decompose(allowRepetitions ? n : (byte)(n + 1), remainder);
                    if (subResults != null)     //we have a remainder and have recursively explored the decomposition of that, which we concatenate to get our results
                    {
                        foreach (byte[] subResult in subResults)
                        {
                            byte[] copy = new byte[subResult.Length + 1];
                            subResult.CopyTo(copy, 1);
                            copy[0] = n;
                            result.Add(copy);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(cachedResult==null)  //if there is a cachedResult it means a result was previously calculated but the min is not low enough so that result is superceded by this one
            {
                cachedResult = new CachedResult();
                cache[f] = cachedResult;
            }
            cachedResult.Min = min;
            cachedResult.Results = result;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Fraction class:

```
/// <summary>
/// A fraction of two whole numbers
/// </summary>
public class Fraction
{
    public static readonly Fraction One = new Fraction(1, 1);

    public readonly long Numerator, Denominator;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new fraction
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numerator"></param>
    /// <param name="denominator"></param>
    public Fraction(long numerator, long denominator)
    {
        if(denominator < 0)
        {
            numerator = -numerator;
            denominator = -denominator;
        }

        long d = GCD(numerator, denominator);
        if(d>1)
        {
            Numerator = numerator / d;
            Denominator = denominator / d; 
        }
        else
        {
            Numerator = numerator;
            Denominator = denominator;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the greatest common divisor of two numbers
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>the greatest common divisor</returns>
    public static long GCD(long a, long b)
    {
        return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Numerator + "/" + Denominator;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds out if this fraction is equivalent to zero
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if this is zero; false otherwise</returns>
    public bool IsZero()
    {
        return Numerator == 0;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (31 * Numerator + Denominator).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(obj==null || !(obj is Fraction))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Equals((Fraction)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(Fraction f)
    {
        return f.Numerator == Numerator && f.Denominator == Denominator;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subtracts another fraction from this fraction
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="f">the other fraction</param>
    /// <returns>a new fraction which is the result of the subtraction</returns>
    public Fraction Subtract(Fraction f)
    {
        return new Fraction(Numerator * f.Denominator - Denominator * f.Numerator, Denominator * f.Denominator);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
    RecipSumToOneCalc calc = new RecipSumToOneCalc(33, false);
    List<byte[]> results = calc.Decompose();
    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\Reciprocals.csv", results.Select(arr => string.Join(",", arr.Select(f => f))));
```

I find on my computer that I can't go about max=33 on my computer with allowRepetitions=false (see above) as I get an out of memory error.  If you remove the dictionary cache, then this would presumably not happen although it is much slower.

I find a lot of the entries in the cache have no results in the value.

**Is their any way of improving this algorithm, i.e. can it be made faster with the same memory usage, or to use less memory with the same efficiency?**

Answer (score 1):

To me a simpler approach would be to calculate the LCM of the denominators as you build a `List<Fraction>`.  Now one more iteration through the list can get a sum of the numerators converted to the LCM equivalent.  If that sum matches the LCM of the denominators the sum of the fractions is 1.  Here's a demonstration that builds the list from the MathML in your sample:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<Fraction> fracs = new List<Fraction>();
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load("xmlfile1.xml");
    long accumulatedLCM = 0;
    foreach(XmlNode n in xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("mfrac"))
    {
        fracs.Add(new Fraction(long.Parse(n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText), long.Parse(n.ChildNodes[1].InnerText)));
        if(fracs.Count() == 2)
        {
            accumulatedLCM = LCM(fracs[0].Denominator, fracs[1].Denominator);
        }
        if(fracs.Count() > 2)
        {
            accumulatedLCM = LCM(accumulatedLCM, fracs.Last().Denominator);
        }
    }
    long numSum = 0;
    foreach(Fraction f in fracs)
    {
        numSum += accumulatedLCM / f.Denominator;
    }
    if(numSum == accumulatedLCM)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("True");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("False");
    }
    return;
}
static long GCD(long a, long b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return GCD(b, a % b);
}
static long LCM(long a, long b)
{
    return a * (b / GCD(a, b));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Document your code better.  In particular, there is quit a bit going on in `Decompose` that is not obvious.  Even some comments you do have lead to more questions than answers.  For example:

  ```
  if (cachedResult.Min <= min)    //match on the fraction found but the minimum is lower so need to remove invalid results
  ```

  How did these "invalid results" get in our cache to begin with?
- What good are `RecipSumToOneCalc` objects?  The only thing we can do with one is call `Decompose()`, which should return the same result no matter how many times it's called.  So there's really not any point to constructing one and passing it around in a program.  It seems like it would be better to make `Decompose` static, and make `RecipSumToOneCalc`'s constructor private.  Alternatively, I suppose we could call `Decompose()` in the constructor -- but usually we don't think of constructors being used for heavy computations like that.
- `Fraction` components are represented using both `long`s and `byte`s.  A `byte` is significantly smaller than a `long`.  (I'm guessing -- but can only guess -- that you use `byte`s because it leads to a smaller memory footprint?  If that's the case, at least document it.)
- Your `Fraction` class uses `long`s to represent numerators and denominators.  This probably isn't an issue for this particular problem, but it would be useful for more problems if `Fraction` supported arbitrary precision.  This could be accomplished via [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Operations on `Fraction`s would be easier to read if you used operator overloading.  For example:

  Fraction remainder = f.Subtract(oneOver);

  would become:

  Fraction remainder = f - oneOver;
- `Fraction` is incomplete.  The only binary operation it supports are `Equals` and `Subtract`.  But even `Subtract` could be expressed in terms of `+` (along with negation).
- Don't reinvent the wheel.  Consider using an [existing implementation of rational numbers](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/88980/rational-numbers-net-version-rational-computin).